# Post can has_many Users with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I had model Event and User (Devise gem) in my ruby on rails application.

So :

- Event model can has_many Users
- User model can has_many Events

Furthermore I need to restrict Post access at some Users with CanCan? You had any idea?

Comment: Start with Google.  Try some stuff.  Post here when you get stuck on a specific problem.

Comment: Start especially not with Google. Start here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ and here http://api.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: I had problem with my search token form, this code not create form in my view :

    <% form_tag events_search_add_path do %>
      <%= text_field_tag 'token', 'Enter your code' %>
      <%= submit_tag 'Add' %>
    <% end %>

Comment: ...honestly add this to the list: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sean Hill is maybe brutal, but yes, you should use Google for this :

- [Two has_many](http://www.google.com/search?q=rails%20two%20has_many) leads to : [has_many :through](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)
- Restric Post access with CanCan, it's in [the CanCan doc](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities).

You should learn to search yourself.

Comment: I had problem with my search token form, this code not create form in my view :

    <% form_tag events_search_add_path do %>
      <%= text_field_tag 'token', 'Enter your code' %>
      <%= submit_tag 'Add' %>
    <% end %>

Comment: You missed a <%= before form_tag ;)

Comment: Yes but I can't found this association .... Dorian I should add "before" before "form_tag" ?

Comment: Non, you should replace `<% form_tag ...` by `<%= form_tag ...`, you missed the "=" who print the result ;). And has_and_belongs_to_many is deprecated, you should use has_many :through => ...

Comment: Thanks :) but has_many :through is for 3 or more Model ?! I need array of user_id who can manage event. It's possible ? you had twitter ?

Comment: For instance : An [event](https://github.com/Ung-UTT/Site-etu-v9/blob/master/app/models/event.rb#L15) can have many users and [users](https://github.com/Ung-UTT/Site-etu-v9/blob/master/app/models/user.rb#L34) can [participate](https://github.com/Ung-UTT/Site-etu-v9/blob/master/app/models/events_user.rb) in many events,. (You can also read the documentation, especially the guides)